# window.close() does not work in an addin Dialog in Windows Excel 2016

Tags: office-js

I'm calling window.close() in a dialog created by Dialog API in Excel 2016 (build 4266) on my windows. But the dialog window will not close. The same code works on Mac Office and Excel online. Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't work, but that wouldn't be the standard way of closing the dialog created by the Dialog API. Generally, you should call dialog.close from the host page. For details see https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the question. No it is not a bug. As mentioned by Ricky you need to call dialog.close from the host page as illustrated on the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). The fact that it works on some platforms is happenstance, its not something that we tested or support.  We do think it makes sense to have a way for the dialog to close itself but if/when we implement it would be an API part of office.js, not the generic window.close.

To expand a bit more, the reason why window.close doesn't work is that the dialog is not just a standard browser window. Depending on the platform and the mode the dialog is displayed using different constructs, for example, on Win32, it is a windows dialog with a webview embedded in it, on Office Online (depending on the mode you set via the API displayAsIframe flag), it is either a new window or a floating div with an Iframe on it.  While we could capture/override window.close to make the dialog close itself it could also lead to confusion as other window methods won't work.  So, at the end of the day, the dialog is an object whose lifecycle is controlled by the platform/APIs that office.js provides, not a generic browser window. The page that you display is required to load office.js to call any of the APIs contained there.  Even if we were to override window.close you would still need to load our javascript for the override to take effect.  So, summary, you do need to load office.js in your page to call our APIs. To close the dialog, today you have to do it from its parent, in the future we want to provide an explicit close method that you can call on the dialog itself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Humberto. My case is the dialog is quite a stand alone page and does not even load office.js. It saves some stuff to our server and I want to have a close button for the user after the work is done. Isn't this a quite common case of using the dialog?

Comment: I edited my answer to expand on the rationale. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing this up, it started up a good internal conversation.  Personally, I do think that we should make `window.close` behave as you expect, especially since it sounds like it already does on two thirds of the platforms.

Regarding your comment to Humberto's answer:  the part about getting this to work without Office.js -- that I'm not physically sure if we can do.  I think you would still need an Office.js reference on the page from which you want to close, otherwise I simply can't imagine how we can monkeypatch the window.close logic.  But at any rate, thanks for bringing this up, we'll think about it...

Comment: hi, can you help me in this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950678/word-add-in-stops-working-after-dialog-close-is-fired-office-js