# Word add-in stops working after dialog.close is fired. Office JS

Tags: office365, office-js

I have been working on an Office365 application where I opened a dialog and after some kind of activity when I close the dialog with dialog.close(). It works perfectly fine but ribbon button stops working and next time it will not show that same dialog again.

```
  Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://" + location.host + "/Dialog.html", { width: 90, height: 90, requireHTTPS: true }, function (asyncResult) {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
        if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            return;
        }
    });
```

and here is my processMessage function

```
function processMessage(arg) {
try{
    var messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);

    var base64 = messageFromDialog.image.split(",")[1];
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var body = context.document.getSelection();
        body.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(base64, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
        return context.sync();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        app.showNotification("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            app.showNotification("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
    if (messageFromDialog.messageType === "dialogClosed") {
        dialog.close();
    }
} catch (ex) {
    console.log("Exception " + ex);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

**Updated**

This issue only occurs in office online.

Comment: hello, can you please add in what Word platform you are experiencing this? (i.e. Windows, Mac, Online?) Also please send us your build number so we can investigate in more detail. thanks!

Comment: @JuanBalmori I am using Windows Word2016.

Comment: can you please share your build number? thanks

Comment: build number? sorry !

Comment: yes if you go to File->Account you will see below the office logo something like Version: XXXX (Build XXXX.XXXX) can you please send that information? thanks!

Comment: Version 1701 (Build 7766.2060)

Comment: thanks! let me investigate in detail!

Comment: @JuanBalmori haven't you get anything yet?

Comment: @JuanBalmori, haven't you get anything yet?

Comment: Hello not yet.. we are investigating.. please be patient

Comment: Hi @JuanBalmori, Is there a timeline or update on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the delay investigating this issue. Long story short, I had to do a couple of changes in your code so this can work, it was throwing a couple of exceptions (see changes below). I did not had the images you are inserting so I am also assuming the base64 you are sending to the method is a valid image. Also FYI please update Office build 16.0.7967.2139  was shipped Apr 21st, but this should also work on the build you cited.

Here are the changes I made:

1. I changed this line to only get the property: var messageFromDialog = arg.message;  (why are you parsing JSON?)
2. I also chagned this one :    if (messageFromDialog === "close"), we dont have a messageType property.(we have type)
   BTW my Dialog.html page looks like this one ( I cannot see yours but i am assuming the user is selecting an image on it)

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- For the Office UI Fabric, go to http://aka.ms/office-ui-fabric to learn more. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/2.1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
    <script>
        Office.initialize = function () {
            $('#button1').click(one);
            $('#button2').click(two);
        };

        function one()
        {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent("Picked 1");
        }

        function two() {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent("close");
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="ms-font-xxl ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontWeight-semilight">Pick a number</p>
    <button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" id="button1">
        <span class="ms-Button-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--plus"></i></span>
        <span class="ms-Button-label" id="button1-text">1</span>
        <span class="ms-Button-description" id="button1-desc">Number 1</span>
    </button>
    <button class="ms-Button ms-Button--primary" id="button2">
        <span class="ms-Button-icon"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--plus"></i></span>
        <span class="ms-Button-label" id="button2-text">2</span>
        <span class="ms-Button-description" id="button2-desc">Number 2</span>
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

3. I also think you are not checking if the dialog was closed properly, you are doing it through the message, but you need so subscribe to the DialogEventReceived event to know if the user closed the dialog (and not with a message).

```js
function showDialog() {


    var url = "https://" + location.host + "/Dialog.html";
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(url, { width: 10, height: 10, requireHTTPS: true }, function (asyncResult) {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
        if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            app.showDialog("OK");
            return;
        }
        else {
            app.showDialog("whats up");
        }
    });

}


function processMessage(arg) {
    try {
        var messageFromDialog = arg.message;
       
        var base64 = messageFromDialog.image.split(",")[1];
        Word.run(function (context) {
var body = context.document.getSelection();
            body.insertInlinePictureFromBase64(base64, Word.InsertLocation.replace);
            return context.sync();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            app.showNotification("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                app.showNotification("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
        if (messageFromDialog === "close") {
            dialog.close();
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log("Exception " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding Point 1 & 2. As soon as I remove the `JSON.Parse`, it starts throwing an exception on the next line `messageFromDialog.image is undefined`. That is, on this line: `var base64 = messageFromDialog.image.split(",")[1];`

Regarding Point 3, I have already handled the event. Please look at my question above. Can you please explain a bit more on how to do this?

It looks like the `messageType` property is there and it is returning the corresponding result as well.

Comment: Here is the `arg` object: 

   `{
       [functions]: ,
       __proto__: { },
       message: "{"messageType":"dialogClosed","image":"data:image/png;base64,---64 string here---"}",
       type: "dialogMessageReceived"
    }`

Comment: @Juan. It looks like. We are doing exactly the same as you have recommended. We are parsing JSON, because, we are putting json in the message after stringifying it and we have already subscribed to the event you mentioned. So what is the output of this post ?

Comment: What office.js are you using? Did you updated office? Is the code working now?

Comment: I updated the office to `16.0.7927.1020`and the same thing is working on that as well. and my Office is saying there is no other update available and the OfficeJs is: `<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: the latest is 16.0.7967.2139 you should be able to update to that build. I am trying your code but I am not able to repro your issue It works ok. I don't know if your base64 is a valid one can you make available the  base64 you are trying to insert? thanks!

Comment: The issue is only reproducing in the Word online. It is working fine for the Desktop version. I thought this was mentioned in the post already, sorry for that... :| Will ask @KhawajaAsim to update the post...

Comment: no comments ? Looks like Microsoft Support is doing a very good job. This issue is opened since 22nd March, more than two months and yet the only involvement was when I posted on github issues reporter... Strange!!!

Comment: Sorry you just mentioned a few days ago that it was in Word Online, prior to that the issue was mentioned to happen on windows only. This is a known issue we are working on a fix. Thanks.

Comment: Any timeline on this known issue. When is it planned to be fixed ?

Comment: @JuanBalmori ??

Comment: @JuanBalmori ting tong

Comment: Hello! we have a repro and working on fix, thanks for following up.